# Is it possible to churn butter in a food processor or blender?

Tags: butter

I would really like to make some homemade butter. Can you make it with a food processor or blender?

Comment: I've done it accidentally (in a food processor), does that count?

Comment: Do you have an ice cream maker? It's so good at making butter it sometimes happens by accident when making ice cream. Try running cream through it without chilling the bowl and see if it works.

Comment: A food processor will work but a mixer will work better if you have one.

Comment: This question has been edited to such an extent that it does not resemble anything I have written.

Comment: @NeilMeyer It's your question. If you want, roll it back. Just hit edit under the butter tag. It will most likely be left alone if you do. I don't see a big difference, but I don't see it the "other" way either (in other words, I don't really see the point in the edits).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, why not? It probably won't turn out quite like the stuff you get at the store, but all you need is cream, a way to churn air into it, and enough agitation that the milk fat molecules start to clump together.

It will require some manual work once you've got the butter and buttercream separated. But the food processor will get you most of the way there without too much of an arm workout.

Check out this [PBS article on DIY butter](http://www.pbs.org/parents/kitchenexplorers/2014/05/22/how-to-make-homemade-butter/) with a food processor.